# Java: what is "best practices" way of controlling what class constructors to call at execution?

Tags: java, constructor, configuration-files, execution-time

I am trying to modify the block below and need to figure out "the right way" to do it:

```
PRQ prq = new PRQ();
XYZ1 xyz1 = new XYZ1();
XYZ2 xyz2 = new XYZ2();

features = new ArrayList<MyFeature>();

// START OF MAIN BLOCK
// This is rigid: need to comment out lines and rebuild to exclude features
// Want to control this at execution time by a config file
//
features.add(new ABCFeatures());
features.add(new PRQFeatures(prq));
features.add(new XYZFeatures(xyz1,xyz2));
// ...
// END OF MAIN BLOCK

public class ABCFeatures extends MyFeature {
    public ABCFeatures()
    {
    }
}

public class PRQFeatures extends MyFeature {
    public PRQFeatures(final PRQ prq)
    {
    }
}

public class XYZFeatures extends MyFeature {
    public XYZFeatures(final XYZ1 xyz1,final XYZ2 xyz2)
    {
    }
}
```

So for every token of input data I compute a bunch of heterogeneous features. Some of those require resources to get computed and those are provided at instantiation (`prq`, `xyz1`, `xyz2`).

Right now if I want to experiment by running my code with some of the features turned off, I need to comment out the corresponding `features.add(new ...` line, rebuild the jar and then rerun. Too rigid! I want to control this at execution using some type of configuration file which says which of the features are on and which are off.

So 2 questions:

1. Looks like I need to use `getClass().getDeclaredConstructors()`, but I am a bit confused about exactly how it's supposed to be used
2. Related to #1 I suppose: Is there a preferred way to specify the configuration? That is, should it be a JSON/XML file in some specific format? Is there existing machinery in Java to support exactly this type of scenario?

Comment: [`Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) might be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `getDeclaredConstructors()`? Just wrap the calls to `features.add(MyFeature)` in an `if` statement that depends on your configuration file.

```
Properties cfg=new Properties();
cfg.load(new FileInputStream("features.properties"));//current directory, default encoding: take care 
if(cfg.getProperty("USE_ABC").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
    features.add(new ABCFeatures());
} 
if(cfg.getProperty("USE_PRQ").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
    features.add(new PRQFeatures(prq));
}
```

Of course you can use constants for property names, a function to encapsulate checking the value of properties, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was trying to be fancy, but I don't think I need anything fancier than your solution. :)